# How to make a hitbox?

Tags: java

I'm making a game similar to mario and I've got this map generated by arrays and images. But my problem is that I don't know how to make a hitbox system for all the tiles. I've tried to have a position based collision system based on your position on the map

like this

```
if(xpos > 10*mapX && xpos < 14 * mapX){
    ypos -= 1;
}
```

But I don't want to that for every wall or hole.
So is there a way to check in front, below and above the character to see if there is a hitbox there and if there is you cant move that direction or fall?

Thank you

Comment: I am no expert in this; but I believe you should evaluate dyn4j (https://code.google.com/p/dyn4j/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a simple 2D game, I'd suggest dividing the map into square tiles. You could store the map in the memory as a two dimensional array and during each frame check tiles adjacent to the player. Of course he can occupy as much as 4 tiles during movement, but it makes you check only up to 12 positions, which can be easily done.

Further collision checking can be done easily using image position and dimension.

Remember that there is no need to check if a static object (environment) is colliding with something, you just need to check objects that have made a move since last frame, i.e. the player and sprites.

**EDIT:**

Let's say you've got the following section of map (variable *map*):

```
...
.pe
ooo
```

where

```
. = nothing
p = player
o = floor
e = enemy
```

you also have the pair `(x, y)` representing *tile indices* (not exact position) of the player. In this case you have to do something like this:

```
if ("o".equals(map[y + 1, x + 1]))
//floor is under
if ("e".equals(map[y, x + 1]))
//enemy is on the right
if ("o".equals(map[y - 1, x]))
//floor is above us
```

If any of these conditions are met, you have to check image positions and handle collisions.

Comment: But how do you check if there is something above below and in front of the character?

Answer (score 0):

Note: clicked submit way after the last post was made...

As Mateusz says a 2D array is best for this type of game:

e.g. using chars:

```
 0123456789012
0           ==
1        * ===
2===== =======
```

So in this case tileMap[8][1] == '*'. You'd probably be best using an enumeration instead of chars though e.g. Tile.SPRING for a Sonic style spring board.

If your map was made up of regular sized tiles you could say:

```
int xInFrontOfPlayer = playerX + PLAYER_WIDTH;
int xBehindPlayer = playerX - PLAYER_WIDTH;

Tile tileInFrontOfPlayer = getTileAtWorldCoord(xInFrontOfPlayer, playerY);
Tile tileBehindPlayer = getTileAtWorldCoord(xBehindPlayer, playerY);

...

public Tile getTileAtWorldCoord(int worldX, worldY) {
    return tileMap[worldX / TILE_WIDTH][worldY / TILE_HEIGHT];
}
```

Where TILE_WIDTH and TILE_HEIGHT are the dimensions of your tiles in pixels. Then use similar math for yAbovePlayer and yBelowPlayer.

You might then have some logic in your game loop:

```
if user is pressing the "go right" key:
      if the tile to the right is Tile.SPACE:
            move player right
      else if the tile to the right is Tile.WALL:
            don't do anything

if the tile below is Tile.SPACE:
    fall
```